# Each second item from mysql in different div box

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 different html div boxes and I want to populate them with data from my database like `div 1 - div 2 - div 1 - div 2`. For this I've tried with counter and make each second box to be `div 2` but seems like doesn't work.. I've got doubled of results.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from projects");
$result->execute();
$counter=0;

for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
{               
    $counter++;
    echo '                  
            <div class="itemm w_30">
                 // load data
            </div>';
    if($counter%2==0)
    {                                       
          echo '<div class="itemm w_40">
                   // load data
                </div> ';                       

    }           
}
```

So on the page I want to see data like

```
<div class="itemm w_30">
     // data
</div>
<div class="itemm w_40">
    // data
</div>
<div class="itemm w_30">
     // data
</div>
<div class="itemm w_40">
    // data
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a ternary operator to set the required class name like this

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from projects");
$result->execute();
$onLeft = true;

while( $row = $result->fetch() ) {               

    $class = $onLeft ? "itemm w_30" : "itemm w_40";

    echo "<div class='$class'>";
        // Show data
    echo '</div>';

    $onLeft = !$onLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put all of your divs in IF ELSE block

```
 if($counter%2==0)
    {                                       
          echo '<div class="itemm w_40">
                   // load data
                </div> ';                       

    } else {
 echo '                  
            <div class="itemm w_30">
                 // load data
            </div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just write first echo on else

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from projects");
$result->execute();
$counter=0;

for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
{               
$counter++;

if($counter%2==0)
{                                       
      echo '<div class="itemm w_40">
               // load data
            </div> ';                       

}  else{
echo '                  
        <div class="itemm w_30">
             // load data
        </div>';
}         
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `%` for loop, no need to use `counter` variable.

```
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
{               
    if($i%2==0)
    {                                       
        echo '<div class="itemm w_40">
                   // load data
                </div> ';                       
    }       
    else
    {
         echo '<div class="itemm w_30">
                 // load data
            </div>';
    } 
}
```